# How can I diagnose which of my PowerShell variables/resources are eating memory?

Tags: powershell, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a complex PowerShell module which polls a bunch of machines for data, munges it, and outputs a CSV. It works great... until I run it across 1000-4000 machines. After a certain point it gradually, but noticeably slows and memory use rises into the 1-4GB range.

After the module has finished running and returns shell control to me, the session retains all of that reserved memory. I didn't realize that variables from the module would persist after the module completed, but running `Get-Variable` shows me I was mistaken.

I've tried removing all of the suspect variables with `Remove-Variable`, while watching Task Manager, and that had no effect. Similarly the few background jobs that somehow remained (even though I'm always using `Remove-Job`) didn't seem to be causing the problem, after manually removing them. However running `[System.GC]::Collect()` did release all of the excess memory.

Is there any way I can get a list of variables/resources within a session and their relative size in memory? Or any other way of easily diagnosing where this "memory leak" is, so that I can try to identify where in the script I can release certain data to optimize performance? I don't like the idea of trying to integrate forced garbage collection, but I'm blind as to what it's doing to solve the issue.

Comment: Easy, just don't save the data in non-local variables in the first place :D kidding aside, in any case, the answer to your question is "it depends" - can you show us an example of what the module is doing?

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure where to start. It's 1200 lines, and I don't really know what would be the most relevant to post, as the code is kind of agnostic to the question (which I realize kind of makes this a poor question). I AM using 5 `$script:var` level variables, which are used for caching info that would otherwise be repeatedly retrieved from our EPM product, however as noted, removing these variables manually after the module completes had no effect on the memory. Am I just mistaken that `Remove-Variable` is supposed to release memory?

Comment: `Remove-Variable` does not directly, it only flags it for the GC.

Comment: without seeing the code, here are a couple of typical gotchas ... [*grin*]  [1] adding to an array with `+=` gobbles up LOTS of RAM. use a `generic.list` that has a real `.Add()` method instead. [2] standard loops load everything into RAM. take a look at using the pipeline instead. that saves RAM at the expense of speed.

Comment: Ditto to what @CrookedJ said, but you can call for GC cleanup at any time, using [[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()]

Comment: Thanks to all so far. Avoiding `+=` and prioritizing pipeline syntax are actionable items. I would be happy to simply add a line to force garbage collection immediately after anywhere I `Remove-Variable`, as that's a real easy fix, but I was under the impression that it wasn't good practice to direct the GC as such. Is there any reason I shouldn't do this? In the meantime I will try running a large test with the additional forced GC and see how that works.

Comment: If you make use of COM objects, you need to release them from memory before calling `[System.GC]::Collect()`. Like this: `$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($obj); [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: Using the forced garbage collection where I thought it would make sense had no effect. My suspicion is that it's not actually the machine data hogging memory, but the cached MECM data. Forcing collection at the END of the script did solve the problem after the script was done, but not mid-execution. I will try other suggestions and see if that helps. I'm still interested if there's a methodology or tool that could help diagnose memory/performance. I'd be happy to close this question as off topic and resubmit it elsewhere, such as softwareengineering.stackexchange.com if that makes more sense.